# Questions about Hyperledger Fabric channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, channel

Does Hyperledger Fabric have the channels first, then peers are joined the channel?

If the computer that created the channel dies, does that channel die? So what's the difference the central network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channels here are similar to the channels you have in messaging applications like slack. You cant have a channel unless you have participants. A channel in hyperledger represents the shared ledger among the parties that are part of the channel.

A channel comprises of participating peers, if a peer is offline, the channel does not cease to exist. You usually have multiple peers per organisation to ensure fault tolerance.

I strongly suggest that you go through the [hyperledger fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)  thoroughly, they explained the architecture extremely well.